# How can I draw a widget on top of the AppBar/TabBar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm making some swipe cards for a mock dating app, but during swiping, they are drawn behind the AppBar...

I've tried using `Overlay.of` and tried moving the TabBar into the AppBar's `body` slot, but to no avail... These ways just throw me a bunch of errors which I just can't seem to fix... Or when I got the TabBar on body working, the cards were still drawn behind it. I've also thought about using `Draggable`, but then I run into the problem of how can I animate the card out of view when the user releases it thus choosing to like/skip.

Sorry for the long ramble, the TL;DR is that is there any way of drawing a widget on top of the TabBar that doesn't involve a million different hacks?

**Update:**
I added some demo code... So basically when swiping, the card goes under the AppBar. It's not such a big deal, but I'm trying to recreate a famous Finnish dating app which doesn't behave like that and I want my recreation to be as accurate as possible, so :D

What would be the best way to approach this problem? I'm not using the Dismissible that I provided in the example, but a custom component, but their implementations are very similar which is why I decided to simplify the demo a bit...

**Demo code:**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() => runApp(const DemoApp());

class DemoApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const DemoApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: false),
      home: const DemoMainPage(),
    );
  }
}

class DemoMainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const DemoMainPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 5,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          systemOverlayStyle:
              const SystemUiOverlayStyle(systemStatusBarContrastEnforced: true),
          toolbarHeight: 0,
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          bottom: TabBar(
            isScrollable: false,
            labelColor: Colors.greenAccent,
            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.green,
            indicator: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.transparent),
            splashBorderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            tabs: const [
              Tab(icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.heart_fill), height: 64),
              Tab(icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.bookmark_fill), height: 64),
              Tab(icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.star_fill), height: 64),
              Tab(icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.chat_bubble_2_fill), height: 64),
              Tab(icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.person_fill), height: 64),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: const TabBarView(
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          children: [
            DemoSwipePage(),
            Center(child: Text("bookmark_fill")),
            Center(child: Text("star_fill")),
            Center(child: Text("chat_bubble_2_fill")),
            Center(child: Text("person_fill")),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DemoSwipePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DemoSwipePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => DemoSwipePageState();
}

class DemoSwipePageState extends State<DemoSwipePage> {
  double cardRotation = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10, top: 5, bottom: 150),
      child: Dismissible(
        key: const Key("some_random_key"),
        child: Transform.rotate(
          angle: cardRotation,
          child: Container(color: Colors.blue),
        ),
        onUpdate: (details) => setState(() {
          cardRotation = details.progress *
              (details.direction == DismissDirection.startToEnd ? 1 : -1) *
              (math.pi / 4);
          // Card rotation does not take into account the directionality of the current context
          // This is not a problem in the implementation that I've written myself.
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you add a reference UI of what you want to achieve? Also post some code of what you have so far.

Comment: @ClevinoAlrin Yeah, I can try to whip up some demos tomorrow if that helps

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added some demo code which hopefully makes it easier to understand the issue I'm facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solved by using Flutter's built-in Overlays.

Soooo... If anyone else has problems with Overlays, I got my solution working by following this tutorial:
https://youtu.be/fhkaDua0rhE?si=hszPkP8g7FvxOcSo

I could've probably learned how overlays work before looking for other solutions...

Comment: can you include answer instead of link

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh Yeah, I should've specified the solution a bit more clearly, I updated my solution to be a bit more specific. I unfortunately don't have an actual solution (as in code) to provide as my implementation is so ingrained into my codebase that there aren't any feasible ways of explaining / providing example code, so this is the best I can do :(